# Deploy multiple Content Delivery Servers with same confguration

Tags: sitecore

I am building out a Sitecore farm with multiple Content Delivery servers. In the current process, I stand up the CD server and go through the manual steps of commenting out connection strings and enabling or disabling config files as detailed here per each virtual machine/CD server:

https://doc.sitecore.net/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/xDB%20configuration/Configure%20a%20content%20delivery%20server

But since I have multiple servers, is there any sort of global configuration file where I could dictate the settings I want (essentially a settings template for CD servers), or a tool where I could load my desired settings/template for which config files are enabled/disabled etc.? I have used the SIM tool for instance installation, but unsure if it offers the loading of a pre-determined "template" for a CD server.

It just seems in-efficient to have to stand up a server then config each one manually versus a more automated process (ex. akin to Sitecore Azure, but in this case I need to install the VMs on-prem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strongly recommend you take a look at [Desired State Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/PowerShell/DSC/overview) which will do exactly what you're talking about. You need to set up the actual configuration at least once of course, but then it can be deployed to as many machines as you'd like.  Changes to the config are automatically flowed to all machines built from the config, and any changes made directly to the machines (referred to as configuration drift) are automatically corrected.  This can be combined with Azure, which now has capability to act as a "pull-server" through the Automation features.

There's a lot of reading to do to get up to speed with this feature-set but it will solve your problem.

This is not a Sitecore tool per se.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing directly in Sitecore to achieve what you want. Depending on what tools you are using then there are some options to reach that goal though.

**Visual Studio / Build Server**

You can make use of [SlowCheetah config transforms](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx) to configure non-web.config files such as ConnetionStrings and AppSettings. You will need a different build profiles for each environment you wish to create a build for and add the appropriate config transforms and overrides. SlowCheetah is available as a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah/) to add to your projects and also a [Visual Studio plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) which provides additional tooling to help add the transforms.

**Continuous Deployment**

If you are using a continuous deployment tool like [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/) then you can [substitute variables in files](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Substitute+Variables+in+Files) on a per environment and machine role basis (e.g. CM vs CD). You also have the ability to write custom PowerShell steps to modify/transform/delete files as required. Since this can also run on a machine role basis you can write a step to remove unnecessary connection strings (master, reporting, tracking.history) on CD environments as well as delete the other files specified in the Sitecore Configuration Guide.

**Sitecore Config Overrides**

Anything within the `<sitecore>` node in `web.config` can be modified and patch using [Include File Patching Facilities](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/60/include_file_patching_facilities_sc6orlater-a4.pdf) built into Sitecore. If you have certain settings which need to be modified or deleted for a CD environment then you can create a CD-specific override, which I place in `/website/App_Config/Include/z.ProjectName/WebCD` and use a post-deployment PowrrShell script in Octopus deploy to delete this folder on CM environment. There are example of patches within the Include folder, such as `SwitchToMaster.config`. In theory you could write a patch file to remove all the config sections mentioned in the depoyment guide, but it would be easier to write a PowerShell step to delete these instead.

I tend to use all the above to aid in deploying to various environments for different server roles (CM vs CD).